# React native and flutter bridging

Tags: flutter

I want to invoke flutter module from react native app, does anyone know how can it be achieved? I was thinking I could call native android function from react native and then invoke flutter module from their. However I am not sure of the recommended practice

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's that easy, because Flutter is from Google and ReactNative is from Facebook, as I'm sure you know. Also, ReactNative uses JavaScript and Flutter uses Dart as its programming language.

It may work somehow, but I highly doubt it.

Comment: React native to android and then invoking flutter module is really lagging, hence poor user experience. I don't know if that's possible to invoke flutter module directly